# publish git branches build to local repository of artifactory

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, artifactory

I have multiple maven projects and one common dependency (maven project too).

- Project1
- Project2
- Common Dependency

Each project has dev,staging,master branches. Everytime I do a merge to those branches, CI/CD will be triggered. Is it ideal to publish the common dependency and have its own local repository?

For ex.

Common Dependency Project

- dev branch will publish to libs-release-dev
- staging to libs-release-staging
- master to libs-release

Project1 or Project2 will resolve the common dependency based on the their branch.

Comment: why do you want to use 3 different versions of the common dependency? I'd suggest publishing one to dev, promote it in Artifactory to staging and prod, and let other modules always use the one in prod. What do I miss?

Comment: Hi JBaruch, thanks for the comment, but how do we test the changes in the common dependency if the other modules will always use the one in prod?

Comment: You should test the common dependency as a unit and promote it in Artifactory from dev to stage to prod based on the results of those tests.